# UWP How to register app as image lockscreen image provider

Tags: windows, uwp, lockscreen

Can anyone tell me how can I register UWP application as lockscreen image provider on windows 10? Couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: No need to register as  aimage provider if you only want to change the lockscreen image. Juat call the UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync method and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Lock​Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen) relative APIs in your UWP app to manage the full-screen image used as the lock screen background.

For sample code please reference the [Personalization](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Personalization) official sample.

Comment: I know how to change background image. But I don't know how to get my application appear on the background list in settings. Unfortunately official sample app is also not shown as an option on the drop down list for background image.

Comment: @turntable, Which list? Did you mean Background list under lock screen settings as [this picture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17185/windows-10-lock-screen) shows?

Comment: Yes, exactly to that list. Do you know how can an app be added there?

Comment: @turntable, why you think an application can be added to this list?  Did you ever see an app be added for using?   Suppose your app can be added to , what's the expect result for the lock screen background when your app choose?